# assert, only once, if variables by vars_prompt are empty

Tags: ansible

I'm asking the user for input and basically I want to check that the value of the variable (asked to the user by vars_prompt) is not empty.

Aborting the playbook when the variable is "" is not a problem and easily done.
However I'm annoyed that this step is ran on a ton of machines while I just want to check it once (I don't see the need to go to a remote machine) and when it's not set I just want the playbook to stop as we know when it's empty the first time it still is the 100s of times afterwards.

Is there a clean way of doing this? I've been experimenting with the assert module but no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`run_once` is your friend:

```
---
- hosts: mygroup
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
    - name: myvar
      prompt: enter myvar
      default: bad_value
  tasks:
    # assert before gathering facts
    - assert:
        that: myvar != 'bad_value'
      run_once: yes
    # gather facts manually with setup
    - setup:
    - debug:
        msg: do the job
```

Also you can disable automatic facts gathering to avoid connections to all your hosts before assertion is done, and collect them manually with `setup`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does this also work in the pre-tasks? I'm using pre-tasks which prevents from doing the setup for all machines first to only then notice the vars are not set correctly. But run_once definitely looks promising. I'll test and give feedback.

Comment: Yes, this work for pre-tasks. pre-tasks works same way as tasks, but are executed before roles. And `setup` task is executed _before_ pre-tasks, if you don't turn off fact gathering. So if you have 100 hosts, Ansible will spend significant amount of time gathering all the facts before testing your assertion. If you disable fact gathering, assertion will be made instantly, and if everything ok, Ansible will gather facts with `setup` module.